# update column only when it is null else dont update

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to update a column only when it is `null` and leave it as it is when it is not `null` in one multiple-columns-update query?
something like below. (like how we use case in select statements)

```
UPDATE users  SET users.city = 'Dallas',
      CASE
          WHEN users.Global_id IS NULL
          THEN
              users.Global_id = '123'
      END WHERE userid = '12312312'
```

The above update statement throws *ORA-00927: missing equal sign* error.

Reason why I am looking for this? 
I have a schedule job that runs a similar query like above. 
And there also exists a trigger in `users` table that will raise error if you try to update a 'not null' `global_id`. So my job fails when it encounters this trigger.

I have one option... to split this update query to two.. one to update city and one to update `global_id` where `global_id is null`.

But wondering if this can be achieved by any other way... Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: guess i can do this. if global_id is null then (update users set users.city = 'Dallas' and users.global_id = '123') else (update users set users.city = 'Dallas') Any other idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [coalesce](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) function:

```
UPDATE users  
SET 
   users.city = 'Dallas',
   users.Global_id = coalesce( users.Global_id, '123')
```

Also, you can split your update in two sentences, remember than you can enclose it in a single transaction:

```
UPDATE users  
SET 
   users.city = 'Dallas';

UPDATE users  
SET 
   users.Global_id = '123'
WHERE
    users.Global_id is null
```

Comment: cant use coalesce but i am planning to split the query as you said

Comment: As i have mentioned in my question, there is a trigger that prevents update on global_id if the global_id is not null.. it throws error on the update query

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of options, but the closest one to your code is this (reformatted and with redundant content removed):

```
UPDATE users SET
    city = 'Dallas',
    Global_id = 
        CASE 
            WHEN Global_id IS NULL THEN '123' 
            ELSE Global_id
        END
WHERE userid = '12312312';
```

However, this is equivalent to the more concise use of the `coalesce()` function:

```
...
    Global_id = COALESCE(Global_id, '123')
...
```

Comment: @Jeevan what are you talking about? I'm saying you can replace the `CASE` with the `COALESCE` call if you want.

Comment: As i have mentioned in my question, there is a trigger that prevents update on global_id if the global_id is not null.. So both the above ways that you have mentioned throws error.

Answer (score 0):

let say you have this column name is not updated `city`

```
(UPDATE users SET city = 'Dallas' WHERE Global_id = your_variable_of_user 
                                 AND   city    = "" )  // it means it null here.
```

the second sql of global id

```
(UPDATE users SET city = 'Dallas' WHERE Global_id = 0 
                                 AND   city    = "" )  // it means it null here.
```

- user_id is your column name of the user id you use
- do you mean global_id will be updated? because if global_id is 0 it means its guest its not logged in so how you will update it ?
  but i advice you to use PDO .
  hope it helps u